# Create a grayscale colorbar for each subplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two polygon patch plots with shading in grayscale, with each patch added to an axis. and I would like to add a colorbar underneath each subplot. 
I'm using

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

poly=mpatches.Polygon(verts,color=rgb,ec='black') #create patch 
ax.add_patch(poly) #add patch to axis 

plt.set_cmap('gray') #grayscale colormap 

        #verts,rgb input created in above lines of code
```

The colorbars should be in grayscale and have range [0,1], with 0 being black, 0.5 marked, and 1 being white. im using subplot(121) and (122).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I cant call plt.colorbar() inside or outside this piece of code, above or below set_cmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use colorbars you have to have some sort of `ScalarMappable` instance (this is used for `imshow`, `scatter`, etc.):

```
mappable = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='gray')
# the mappable usually contains an array of data, here we can
# use that to set the limits
mappable.set_array([0,1])   
ax.colorbar(mappable)
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me; where does m come from? are you referencing an imported library?

Comment: sorry about that, that was a copy/paste error: Now it should be fine

Answer (score 2):

I might be late here but now matplotlib has unique functionality to set colormap to gray as shown in this [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gray.html).

```py
plt.gray()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0, right = 1, top = 1, bottom = 0)
im = plt.imshow(output)
pos = fig.add_axes([0.93, 0.1, 0.02, 0.35])  # Set colorbar position in fig
fig.colorbar(im, cax=pos)  # Create the colorbar
plt.savefig(os.path.join(args.output_path, image_name))
```

the line 1 will set your colormap to grayscale. the result is shown in the image. [image]